# Move a few last commits to another repository?

Tags: git

We have 2 Git repos - one production and another is test one. Is it possible that I move 3 last commits from the test one to the production repo?

They both are in sync meaning that the production repo is currently at commit no.50, and the test repo is on commit no.53. So only the last 3 are new.

Right now I worked in a way that I copied test repo to production one and git would see what's new and would commit only those files to the production repo. Not a nice approach, but it works. Yet it's tedious and error prone so I am trying to find an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving commits between repositories is always push/pull/fetch. I.e.

```
/test/repo $ git push path/to/production/repo fromWhichBranch:toWhichBranch
```

or vice versa:

```
/prod/repo $ git pull path/to/test/repo
```

or

```
/prod/repo $ git fetch path/to/test/repo
/prod/repo $ git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the source repo into the destination one as a secondary remote. Do

```
git remote add source_repo path/to/source/repo
git fetch source_repo
```

This way you can just cherry pick commits from test to prod, just make sure you're on the right branch and do `git cherry-pick <commit_id>`

For example if you want to copy a commit with id `commit_a` from test to prod, got to the prod repo, and do:

```
git remote add test_repo path/to/test/repo
git fetch test_repo
git cherry-pick commit_a
```

If the two repo's will always share the same parent, meaning production repo will always eventually have the same commits in test, you can do a rebase when you're in the production repo after adding test as a remote:

```
git rebase test_repo/master master
```

Comment: I never used cherry-pick method. Can you explain it in more details? Since you have experience, please share things that I should avoid not to mess things up.

Comment: @sandalone you can read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). All it does is copy a code change given by the commit_id into the current branch you're on.

Comment: Cherry pick is bad idea for his history

Comment: I agree, it is what he asked for though, I expanded the answer to add the option to rebase if production will always have all test's commits.

Comment: Why not simple merge? In his case it even will be fast-forward.